# Performance Testing for Native Mobile Applications

Tags: android, performance, mobile, apk, performance-testing

I have to do a POC on Performance Testing for a Native Mobile Application. Need some help on how to go ahead. Many tools in the market work on a browser based on the Mobile. What if, I have developed an app (eg: like Facebook app on Android phone) and want to test load/Volume/Stress. A heads up would be that we have developed an .apk file and installed it on the mobile device. The App is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UI Test/Performance/Stress** (app crawlers / monkey testing)

- Android Monkey http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html
- Monkop http://monkop.com/
- Others: AppThwack, Testdroid, GameBench

**Load/Volume** (api oriented)

- Blazemeter
- Apica